# Mockito- thenReturn(true) still returns false on a mock object

Tags: unit-testing, testing, mockito

I recently started reading up about Mockito. The following line of code must return true as per my understanding, but it returns false.

Test Class

```
public class PersonServiceImplTest {

   Car car;

   @InjectMocks 
   CarServiceImpl carService;

   @Mock    
   CarDAOImpl carDAO;

   @Before
   public void setUp() {
     MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
   }


   @Test
   public void testUpdateCar() {
     int carId = 1;
     Mockito.when(carDAO.getCarById(any(Integer.class))).thenReturn(new Car());
     carService.updateCar(carId);
Mockito.when(carDAO.isLicenseExpired(any(Car.class))).thenReturn(true);
     Mockito.verify(carDAO).updateCar(any(Car.class));
     Mockito.verify(carDAO, times(1)).isLicenseExpired(any(Car.class));
     Mockito.verify(carDAO, times(1)).issueLicense(any(Car.class));
   }
}
```

Class to be tested

```
public class CarServiceImpl implements CarService {

@Autowired carDAO carDAO;

@Override
public Response updateCar(int carId) {

    Car car =carDAO.getCarById(carId);

    try {

        carDAO.updateCar(car);

        if(carDAO.isLicenseExpired(car)))
            carDAO.issueLicense(car);

    } catch (Exception e) {

        log.error(e.getMessage());

        return Response.status(Status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).build();

    }

    return Response.ok(Status.CREATED).build();
}
```

CarDAOImpl deals with the database, if needed, will update that too.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Should I do it in the setUp method where I currently do MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this); or in the test method itself?

Comment: Depends if you want to re-use the same object for multiple tests - then in the setup, otherwise, in the test itself. Where in your code you're executing: `Mockito.when...thenReturn..` ?

Comment: Tried, doesn't help.

Comment: So, either (a) the instance of `SomeDaoImpl` in `ServiceImpl` is **not** a mock at runtime or (b) `mockedObject.anyMethod(any(Integer.class))` is not matched. Have you **verified** whether the instance of `SomeDaoImpl` in `ServiceImpl` is a mock during your test invocation? Can you post the definition of `anyMethod` on `SomeDaoImpl`?

Comment: @glytching How do I check (a) ?


And (b) is matched because I'm able to verify if anyMethod is invoked or not. Also, when I `System.out.println(Mockito.when(mockedObject.anyMethod(any(Integer.class))).thenReturn(true));` it does print false.

Comment: You can check a/ by debugging your code or by logging the **class name** for the instance of `ServiceDaoImpl` which is in injected into `ServiceImpl`.

Comment: @glytching `class packageName.SomeDAOImpl$MockitoMock$785238046` is the class that gets printed in ServiceImpl.

Comment: Ok, so that's definitely a mock. Probably need [more detail](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in order to help diagnose this issue.

Comment: @glytching Hey, I have edited my question. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These two lines are ordered incorrectly:

```
carService.updateCar(carId); 
Mockito.when(carDAO.isLicenseExpired(Mockito.any(Car.class))).thenReturn(true);
```

The first line in that pair invokes the class-under-test and the second line sets up an expectation of how your `carDAO` should behave inside the class-under-test. So, you are setting the expectation **after** you invoke the class-under-test.

The following test will pass:

```
@Test
public void testUpdateCar() {
    int carId = 1;

    // establish expectations of how carDAO should behave inside updateCar()
    Mockito.when(carDAO.getCarById(Mockito.any(Integer.class))).thenReturn(new Car());
    Mockito.when(carDAO.isLicenseExpired(Mockito.any(Car.class))).thenReturn(true);

    // invoke the class-under-test
    carService.updateCar(carId);

    // verify that CarService used CarDAO correctly
    Mockito.verify(carDAO).updateCar(Mockito.any(Car.class));
    Mockito.verify(carDAO).isLicenseExpired(Mockito.any(Car.class));
    Mockito.verify(carDAO).issueLicense(Mockito.any(Car.class));
}
```

Comment: I was writing some other method and it worked, so I thought it was the order. Reordered and it worked. Came back here to find the same answer. :)

Thanks for your time and the explanation.