# next thenReturn still returns previous result of thenThrow

Tags: java, mockito

I saw similar questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47346291/mockito-thenreturntrue-still-returns-false-on-a-mock-object) and others with answers but the accepted/voted answers didnt work for me. Class Outgoing depends on TransManager, whose method I want to mock.

Now the test deleteInvoiceReIssue fails because the mock.thenReturn() doesn't have effect. Instead,the previous thenThrow is still remembered.

I did try with nested returns (thenThrow and thenReturn) in one test but saw no difference either.

```
package com.invoicestracker;

@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class OutgoingTest {
    private static String cPoint = "test";
    private TransManager mockedTransManager;
    private Outgoing mockedOutgoing;


    @Before
    public void setUp(){
        mockedTransManager = mock(TransManager.class);
        mockedOutgoing = new Outgoing(context, mockedTransManager);
    }


    @After
    public void recreateMocks(){
        reset(mockedTransManager);
        mockedTransManager = mock(TransManager.class);
        mockedOutgoing = new Outgoing(context, mockedTransManager);
    }



    @Test
    public void deleteInvoice() {
        //InvoiceException is a custom exception
        InvoiceException ex = new InvoiceException("Invoice Exception");
        when(mockedTransManager.deleteInvoice(any()))
                .thenThrow(ex);
        Boolean result = mockedOutgoing.deleteInvoice(cPoint, false);
        assertThat(result).isEqualTo(false);
    }

    @Test
    public void deleteInvoiceReIssue() {
        //the mock below always returns an exception from the above  
        when(mockedTransManager.deleteInvoice(any())).thenReturn(true);
       Boolean result =  mockedOutgoing.deleteInvoice(cPoint, true);
       assertThat(result).isEqualTo(true); //fails, expected true but got false
    }

    // also tried
    
    @Test
    public void deleteInvoice() {
        //InvoiceException is a custom exception
        InvoiceException ex = new InvoiceException("Invoice Exception");
        when(mockedTransManager.deleteInvoice(any()))
                .thenThrow(ex)
                .thenReturn(true);
        Boolean result = mockedOutgoing.deleteInvoice(cPoint, false);
        assertThat(result).isEqualTo(false);

        //delete with reissue.
         Boolean result =  mockedOutgoing.deleteInvoice(cPoint, true);
       assertThat(result).isEqualTo(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Simple fix: move `mockedTransManager = mock(TransManager.class);` from setup to inside your methods. Superior fix: stop using mockito, powermock, et al and start using [Spock](https://spockframework.org/) - it’s awesome and you’ll never look back

Comment: The each test run independently please check that expectation same as previous one check exception message.

Comment: Does your `TransManager` class have several `deleteInvoice` methods? Your `when` is only matching one parameter, but you call `deleteInvoice` with two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to test `Outgoing` so it is not mocked nut it uses mocks internally. You could make your test by using Mockito annotations, like:

```
@Mock
private TransManager mockedTransManager;
@Mock
private Context context;
@InjectMocks // sets above mocks to outgoing
private Outgoing outgoing;
```

which then makes your `@Before` & `@After` needless.

I assume here that `InvoiceException extends RuntimeException` because you have not delared any `throws`. With above changes and assumption I have no problems to get these working:

```
@Test(expected = InvoiceException.class)
public void deleteInvoice() throws InvoiceException {
    InvoiceException ex = new InvoiceException("Invoice Exception");
    when(mockedTransManager.deleteInvoice(any())).thenThrow(ex);
    outgoing.deleteInvoice(cPoint, false);
}

@Test
public void deleteInvoiceReIssue() {
    when(mockedTransManager.deleteInvoice(any())).thenReturn(true);
    assertTrue(outgoing.deleteInvoice(cPoint, true));
}
```